How to define different range in gauge chart of Go ECharts?
I wanted to give custom range in the gauge chart for example:
from 0-30 : Green
from 31-65 : Orange
From 66-100 : Red
How can I achieve it ? Could someone please help ?
https://github.com/go-echarts/examples/blob/master/examples/gauge.go
func gaugeBase() *charts.Gauge {
    gauge := charts.NewGauge()
    gauge.SetGlobalOptions(
        charts.WithTitleOpts(opts.Title{Title: "basic Gauge example"}),
    )

    gauge.AddSeries("ProjectA", []opts.GaugeData{{Name: "Work progress", Value: rand.Intn(50)}})
    return gauge
}

func gaugeTimer() *charts.Gauge {
    gauge := charts.NewGauge()
    gauge.SetGlobalOptions(
        charts.WithTitleOpts(opts.Title{Title: "javascript timer"}),
    )

    gauge.AddSeries("ProjectB", []opts.GaugeData{{Name: "Work progress", Value: rand.Intn(50)}})

    fn := fmt.Sprintf(`setInterval(function () {
            option_%s.series[0].data[0].value = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(2) - 0;
            goecharts_%s.setOption(option_%s, true);
        }, 2000);`, gauge.ChartID, gauge.ChartID, gauge.ChartID)
    gauge.AddJSFuncs(fn)
    return gauge
}

Sample output:

